# Connecting both Parent and Child to Redux store causes Typescript error when child's props are not passed in the place of its declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I, actually, have my components working and I know that there is a different way of achieving the same result by passing props from Parent to Child. But I am still asking for the sake of understanding - is it just a TypeScript "feature" or I don't understand some concepts?

So, there is a Parent component linked to Redux store and it has a Child. Here is Parents render method:

```
render() {
const { isAuthenticated, ... } = this.props;

return (
        ...
        <AccountMenu isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
        ...
);
```

Here is the child (I removed non-related code):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { IRootState } from 'app/shared/reducers';
import { AccountCircle } from '@material-ui/icons';
import { IconButton, Menu, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export interface IAccountMenuState {
  anchorEl: boolean;
}

class AccountMenu extends Component<StateProps, IAccountMenuState> {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu id="simple-menu" anchorEl={anchorEl} open={Boolean(anchorEl)} onClose={this.handleClose}>
          {isAuthenticated ? (
            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose} component={logout}>
              Logout
            </MenuItem>
          ) : (
            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose} component={login}>
              Login
            </MenuItem>
          )}
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ authentication }: IRootState) => ({
  isAuthenticated: authentication.isAuthenticated
});

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(AccountMenu);
```

As you can see in Child component I access "isAuthenticated" property directly from Redux store and have StateProps type set for the component:

```
class AccountMenu extends Component<StateProps, IAccountMenuState> {
```

Setting it above doesn't let me add this Child to Parent without passing isAuthenticated as a props. So, this in Parent component will not work:

```
return (
        ...
        <AccountMenu/>
        ...
);
```

What should I do in such cases: when I have my component directly connected to Redux store, so the value required is taken from there, but TypeScript still forces me to pass the same value from Parent component. Otherwise type checking is not passed and I get an error:

> TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly>'.   Property
>   'isAuthenticated' is missing in type '{}'

As a workaround I can just add isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} as a prop for Child component. But in this case I don't understand which value is being used in Child component: the one which I passed from Parent or the one from Store which I refer directly? I am certain that it is the value from store which is used when it changes, but what is the initial value for Child I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your props:

```
export interface IAccountMenuState {
  anchorEl?: boolean;
  isAuthenticated?: any;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the point in defining something which is taken from Redux store (which means that it is passed to component as a prop) in component's state? I thought that I don't need to map values taken from store as props to internal state.

Comment: In typescript you need to map everything you want inside your props. You are getting this error because you have added a prop isAuthenticated, but you have not added the type of the prop. Since typescript is strictly typed and need every information about the prop types you need to specify. Now the main scene comes when you are rendering that component. You have added a prop and you didn't added ? Then it is considered as required that's why we add ? For the props coming directly from the store